# Go Struct Fields Undefined

Tags: go, if-statement, structure

Learning Go as I work through creating a REST API.  Getting the error `undefined: authDetails` when I use it the two times at the bottom to access the fields.  I understand that it's set in a branch that may not be executed.  I've tried moving it outside of the branch, or declaring it above with `var authDetails auth.AccessDetails` and then setting the values afterwards.  I've also tried moving the assignment outside of the braces, but no matter what I do it doesn't seem to carry the values from within the conditional block out to where I try to use them.

I think I'm misunderstanding something regarding scope, if someone could assist me in understanding what the problem is it would be a huge help.

The Struct definition is:

```
type AccessDetails struct {
    AccessUuid string
    UserId   uint64
}
```

and the code is:

```
func (server *Server) GetTokenUserIDFromRequest(r *http.Request) (uint64, error) {
    var authDetails auth.AccessDetails
    tokenString := auth.ExtractToken(r)
    token, err := jwt.Parse(tokenString, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodHMAC); !ok {
            return 0, fmt.Errorf("Unexpected signing method: %v", token.Header["alg"])
        }
        return []byte(os.Getenv("API_SECRET")), nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    claims, ok := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)
    if ok && token.Valid {
        accessUuid, ok := claims["access_uuid"].(string)
        if !ok {
            return 0, errors.New("token not valid, cannot retrieve access_uuid")
        }
        userid, err := strconv.ParseUint(fmt.Sprintf("%.0f", claims["user_id"]), 10, 64)
        if err != nil {
            return 0, err
        }

        authDetails := &auth.AccessDetails{
            AccessUuid: accessUuid,
            UserId: userid,
        }
    }
    
    redisuserid, err := server.RedisClient.Get(authDetails.AccessUuid).Result()
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    userID, _ := strconv.ParseUint(redisuserid, 10, 64)
    if userID != authDetails.UserId {
        return 0, errors.New("userid from token does not match userid from database")
    }
    return userID, nil
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redeclaring `authDetails` in the `if`-block instead of setting the value declared at the outer scope. The relevant section in the language specification is:

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations

Instead of `authDetails:=...` use `authDetails=...`, so it becomes an assignment, not a declaration.

Comment: I see what you're saying but if I move it outside of the if-block then I can't assign the values as they become undefined.

Comment: After adding the declaration at the top ```var authDetails auth.AccessDetails``` and then making your suggested change it seems to be working.  Though I could have sworn I had tried this already.

Comment: You have `authDetails` defined at the top of the function. Simply use `=` instead of `:=` to set that `authDetails` you declared at the top.

Comment: Ah, I had removed the declaration at the top since I posted which was the source of the confusion.  Thank you for the assistance.